in MySQL generated columns referring to current_timestamp fail
Given this table structure:
CREATE TABLE t3 (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `abc` bigint NOT NULL,
  `ts` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `createdday` int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cast(`ts` as date)) STORED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

In one MySQL version 8.0.25 instance, when we do insert into t3 (abc) values (2); it can successfully write the row and createdday can has right value, but in another MySQL instance with same version, it shows  error ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'createdday' cannot be null.
In MySQL bug list, the was a question about this https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94550,  but there is no update in it.
I checked the configuration variables, they are same. Especially the explicit_defaults_for_timestamp is OFF. Anyone knows why one of the MySQL instances can save it in right way but another cannot? and how to fix this?
2024/09/21 Update:
Did more tests with different MySQL versions, I found that in MySQL 8.0.23 it is allowed to run that insert statement and successfully write the data, but when I upgrade to 8.0.24, it starts to error out with column cannot be null. I think this change starts from 8.0.24.

If you think its a bug, Stack Overflow is not the correct place for this question.

Difference in table definition SHOW CREATE TABLE t3 or SQL Modes  SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode; and SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode; .. etc...

You cannot refer on non-deterministic data in generated column expression. This is NOT a bug, this is ideological point.

@Akina I'm not saying it's a bug, but it has different behavior in different instances. If it should be an error when I use a non-deterministic data, why one of the can successfully write the row?

Does the table have the exact same definition on both instances? Including the same STORED and NOT NULL options?

@Akina They're not using the function in the column expression. It's just in the default value of the other column. When the column expression is evaluated, the other column should be filled in with a specific timestamp.

@BillKarwin yes, the columns have exact same definition.

@Barmar AGREE! From my understanding, it should act like you said, use the evaluated value of the original column to generate the value for the generated column.

I made some tests on MySQL version 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.22.04.1.
Table description
CREATE TABLE `t3` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `abc` bigint NOT NULL,
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `createdday` int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cast(`ts` as date)) STORED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB


mysql> insert into t3(abc) values(1);
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'createdday' cannot be null

With explicit_defaults_for_timestamp session and global set to OFF and ON the same error occurred, but if I used the following query
mysql> insert into t3(abc,ts) values(1,current_date());
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from t3;
+----+-----+---------------------+------------+
| id | abc | ts                  | createdday |
+----+-----+---------------------+------------+
|  1 |   1 | 2024-09-19 00:00:00 |   20240919 |
+----+-----+---------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
 

It works just fine.

Using DATETIME the error did not occur.
 CREATE TABLE `t4` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `abc` bigint NOT NULL,
  `ts` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `createdday` int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (cast(`ts` as date)) STORED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

mysql> insert into t4(abc) values(1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from t4;
+----+-----+---------------------+------------+
| id | abc | ts                  | createdday |
+----+-----+---------------------+------------+
|  1 |   1 | 2024-09-19 17:47:10 |   20240919 |
+----+-----+---------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


In the manual I can't find a proper solution to this behavior CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns

If a generated column uses the TIMESTAMP data type, the setting for
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp is ignored. In such cases, if this
variable is disabled then NULL is not converted to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
If the column is also declared as NOT NULL, attempting to insert NULL
is explicitly rejected with
ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR


I don't understand why DATETIME can run but TIMESTAMP can't. From my understanding, whichever the type is, it is just using the default value of the other column. When the original column's default value expression is evaluated, the generated column should be filled in with the value.
